# Unity: OnMouseEnter() and OnMouseExit() are repeatedly called while OnMouseDrag()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse

While OnMouseDrag() is called, if I move mouse fast then OnMouseEnter() and OnMouseExit() are repeatedly called, so I made a new script but the same problem happens. If I move mouse slowly, they aren't called. I don't know what's the problem. Anyone can help me?

I hope they are not called while dragging. While I drag, the object is attached to the mouse so I think OnMouseEnter() and OnMouseExit() shouldn't be called.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        // If mouse enters the object, the color of the object becomes red and prints "Enter"
        Debug.Log("Enter");
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
    }

    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        // If mouse exits the object, the color of the object becomes white and prints "Exit"
        Debug.Log("Exit");
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.white;
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        // If I click the object and drag, it follows mouse
        // Then OnMouseEnter() and OnMouseExit() is called repeatedly
        // and the color becomes red and white and both "Enter" and "Exit" are printed
        // Utilities.MousePos has the position of mouse, and it doesn't have any problem.
        transform.position = Utilities.MousePos;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a similar question on unity forum, but it wasn't helpful.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/onmouseenter-onmouseexit-called-repeatedly-while-dragging.28580/

Comment: Shouldn't, maybe. But it does!
For dragging you need to calculate the first touch/click point and subtract it from the "up point".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because `OnMouseEnter()` and `OnMouseExit()` is handled before `OnMouseDrag()`. So every frame there are things like this happen:

1. You move your mouse and Unity handle that its position changed
2. Unity checked the mouse and object positions and see, that mosue moved outside the object, so `OnMouseExit()` is being called. *As your metion it happens if you move your mouse fast enough to make it leave object with one frame*
3. Unity hande drag event and call `OnMouseDrag()`. The position of object changed in it.
4. Cause position of object changing Untiy again checking for mouse and object positions and find out that mouse cursor is over the object. And call `OnMouseEnter()`

The workaround, that I cant suggest is to implement own dragging logic like this:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class DraggableObj : MonoBehaviour
{

    private bool _hovered;
    private bool _dragged;
    
    private bool Hovered {
        set
        {
            _hovered = value;
            UpdateState();
        }
        get => _hovered;
    }
    
    private bool Dragged {
        set
        {
            _dragged = value;
            UpdateState();
        }
        get => _dragged;
    }
    
    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        Hovered = true;
    }
    
    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        Hovered = false;
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Dragged = true;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        Dragged = false;
    }

    private void UpdateState()
    {
        if (Hovered || Dragged)
            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        else 
            gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Dragged)
        {
            // Here you should implement your positioning logic. This one is just for example.
            transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + Vector3.forward * 10f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was helpful. I'd like to know why this doesn't working, not how to make it work. But I have one more question: I also thought that I dragged mouse too fast so the mouse leave the object in one frame, so I set the size of collider large enough so the mouse never leave the the object, but same problem happened. Is it a similar problem with this?

Comment: I, personally, can't reproduce it with large collider sizes. You also need to understand, that this problem will be unreproducable if collider will cover entire screen space. Otherwise there will always be a speed, that will be high enough to leave object with one frame.